# Excel 2003 VBA PivotTable Show Specific Items

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to only show 5 specific items in my pivottable. The table consists of around 50 different items, so I want to hide everything apart from these 5 items, but am struggling.
The best result I can get is removing everything, then showing the 5 items, but as you cannot remove all it will always leave the last item in the table.
Could someone help me with this please?

```
Dim pvtitem As PivotItem

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PIV4").PivotFields("MSG TYPE")
    .PivotItems("TEXT1").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("TEXT2").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("TEXT3").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("TEXT4").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("TEXT5").Visible = True

For Each pvtitem In .PivotItems
    If Not pvtitem.Name Like "TEXT1" Then pvtitem.Visible = False
    ElseIf Not pvtitem.Name Like "TEXT2" Then pvtitem.Visible = False
    ElseIf Not pvtitem.Name Like "TEXT3" Then pvtitem.Visible = False
    ElseIf Not pvtitem.Name Like "TEXT4" Then pvtitem.Visible = False
    ElseIf Not pvtitem.Name Like "TEXT5" Then pvtitem.Visible = False
    Next pvtitem
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below (I've added a `Select Case` so you can easily add/modify your |Pivot Field "MSG TYPE" Filter conditions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter_PivotItems()

Dim pvtTbl          As PivotTable
Dim pvtitem         As PivotItem
Dim pvtFld          As PivotField

Set pvtTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PIV4")

' set Pivot field variable to "MSG TYPE"
Set pvtFld = pvtTbl.PivotFields("MSG TYPE")

' lop through all Pivot Items in "MSG TYPE" Pivot Field
For Each pvtitem In pvtFld.PivotItems

    Select Case pvtitem.Name
        Case "TEXT1", "TEXT2", "TEXT3", "TEXT4", "TEXT5"
            pvtitem.Visible = True

        Case Else
            pvtitem.Visible = False

    End Select

Next pvtitem

End Sub
```